# Adding filtering changes ordering

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet that I want to add filtering to. My simple model looks like

```
class Article(models.Model):
    date = = models.DateField()
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

And the ModelViewSet (read only):

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

Articles on the API are now ordered by date descending as I would expect. Now I wich to allow filtering on language. I've set the filter backend to `DjangoFilterBackend` in settings.py. My updated ModelViewSet now looks like:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_fields = ['language']
```

This changes the ordering to language ASC. Adding `order_by('-date')` to queryset does not change anything. Adding `ordering = ('-date', )` does not change anything. => How do I specify both filtering and ordering (or simply use default ordering while allowing filtering)?

**EDIT:**
Current functionality seems to come from AutoFilterSet created in Rest Framework by default:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/822eb39599b248c68573c3095639a831ab6df99a/rest_framework/filters.py#L53
... where `order_by=True` and the handing of this in django-filter `get_ordering_field` here: https://github.com/alex/django-filter/blob/d88b98dd2b70551deb9c128b209fcf783b325acc/django_filters/filterset.py#L325

=> Seems I have to create a FilterSet class:

```
class LanguageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['language']
        order_by = model()._meta.ordering

class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    filter_class = LanguageFilter
```

Does this look correct? Seems a bit "much"/verbose to retain default ordering.

Comment: Ordering is database/query specific and potentially arbitrary unless you explicitly set an order. Any user-facing list should have an order-by.

Comment: Ordering already set on Article.Meta - which is respected until starting to filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than implementing your own `FilterSet`, you can instead just add an [`OrderingFilter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#orderingfilter), specifying an `ordering = ['-date']` or better: `ordering = Article._meta.ordering` on your view, to restore the lost (default) ordering. This would also allow your users to use an `ordering` query parameter to override your default ordering of results.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this issue has been resolved in master... https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1836 and is due to be released in version 2.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Is ok to apply an ordering filter in conjuction with a Django-Filter but I think is not right that a Filter Backend applies a reorder function.

In my case I have to cache my random queryset and so i can't use Django-Filter anymore, even if I'm not filtering at the page's first asyncronous call.